# Prolog repeating the same answer infinitely

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

These are my facts:

```
married(man, widow).
married(father,daughter).
married(widow, man).
married(daughter,father).

parent(father, man).
parent(widow, daughter).
parent(man, bboy).

% here is the rule giving me problems,

parent(X,Y):-
   married(Z,X),
   parent(Z,Y).
```

when I run parent(X,Y) it returns the same answers infinitely as such

```
  ?- parent(X,Y).

X = father
Y = man ? ;

X = widow
Y = daughter ? ;

X = man
Y = bboy ? ;

X = widow
Y = bboy ? ;

X = widow
Y = daughter ? ;

X = widow
Y = bboy ? ;

X = widow
Y = daughter ? ;
```

How do I stop it from repeating, because when another rule calls the parent rule it crashes prolog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
parent(X,Y):-
    married(Z,X),
    parent(Z,Y).
```

Actually, you can see it a little more clearly if you remove `married/2`:

```
parent(X,Y):-
    parent(Z,Y).
```

This is going to lead to unbounded recursion. The simple thing to do is rename either the rule or the facts:

```
parent(father, man).
parent(widow, daughter).
parent(man, bboy).

parent_of(X, Y) :-
    married(Z, X),
    parent(Z, Y).
```

No more recursion.